# Is it possible to change direction of flowing water vapor particles via static electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, fluid-dynamics

It is a well known fact that we can bend flowing water with static electricity. However, I am trying to figure out if this is the case for the water vapor as well, and if yes or not why. My professor thinks it is possible though the vapor particles touching the static electricity source would get charged and fly back rapidly, creating a turbulent flow.
In order to test this, I have conducted the following basic epxeriment. I grabbed my roommate's cold mist machine and attached a metal straw to its nozzle so that the vapor/mist would come out in a streamline, making it possible to see any deviations in the direction. Then, I have charged a plastic rod and brought it near the flowing vapor. However, I have seen no effects at all. I am sure that the rod was charged because it attracted both water drops and paper pieces.

I am confused since theoretically, just as my professor thinks, there is no reason for static electricity to not bend the flowing vapor since it is a polar fluid just like water, and, even more, I, unfortunatelly, could not find any research or work on this topic as well.

Comment: I think initially the gas molecules will be partially polarised by induction and will get attracted to the source of electric field .

Comment: What you see coming out of the mist machine are fine liquid droplets (likely less than 10 micron size), not gaseous vapour particles (the latter are invisible). The reason why those droplets didn't respond to the electric field that you applied may be that the applied field was too weak, or equivalently there is very little charge on those droplets.